# Get data on the basis of comma-separated ids present in row - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

**Table1**

```
                HolId
1   Package17   2,1,5
2   Package13   5,4,3
```

**Table 2**

```
 HolId1
    1   New Years Day   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
    2   Republic Day    2013-01-26 00:00:00.000
    3   Holi            2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
    4   Memorial Day    2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
    5   US Independence 2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
    7   Labour Day  2013-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

I want to display data like below

```
         HolId    HolId1
Package17   2   2   Republic Day    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Package17   1   1   New Years Day   2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
Package17   5   5   US Independence 2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
Package13   5   5   US Independence 2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
Package13   4   4   Memorial Day    2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
Package13   3   3   Holi            2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
```

My grid will be displayed as follows which i have figured out

```
Package17

     Republic Day   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
    New Years Day   2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
    US Independence 2013-05-27 00:00:00.000

Package13   

    US Independence 2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
    Memorial Day    2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
    Holi            2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Step 0) Normalize your data.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  SQL Server, MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solution for `MySQL`:

```
SELECT
T1.Pkg, T2.*
FROM Table2 T2
    JOIN Table1 T1
        ON FIND_IN_SET(T2.HolID1, T1.HolID)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c3c/4)**

and this is for `SQL SERVER`

```
SELECT
T1.Pkg, T2.*
FROM Table2 T2
    JOIN Table1 T1
        ON CHARINDEX(CAST(T2.HolID1 as varchar), T1.HolID) > 0
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/314dd/1)**

Comment: It has an issue if the id is two digit say 29

Comment: @vini It is because you have 5 in both sets.

Comment: no no the issue is if i have say 28 id in the first comma separated row and in the second table 2 and 8 and 28 so it displays  data corresponding to 2 and 8 also which it shoudnt as they aren't present in the first table

Answer (score 0):

Better to de-normalize your table, then just one join you can get your result. If you have to use the current schema. Hope the following code help you.

```
declare @tempTable table 
     ( Package_Name varchar(100),
       Holid int
       )

declare @SQLString varchar(max)
declare @package_name varchar(100)
set @SQLString = ''
DECLARE @X XML
while @SQLString is not null
begin
set @SQLString = null
select top 1 @package_name=package_name, @SQLString = Holid 
from Package 
where package_name not in (select package_name from @tempTable)
if @SQLString is null
   break
SET @X = CAST('' + REPLACE(@SQLString, ',', '') + '' AS XML)
insert into @tempTable
SELECT @package_name, t.value('.', 'INT')
FROM @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)
end
select * from @tempTable
select A., B.* from @tempTable A
inner join HolID1 B
on A.Holid = B.HolID1
```